# Regular expression for "-" in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to know how can I get a regular expression for matching `number`, `.`, and `-` only.

I am using this:

```
/^[0-9\.'S]+$/
```

by this it working fine but not working for symbol "-".

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: You probably want `-` instead of `'S`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `-` is not part of your character class. You are only using `-` in the class range (which only includes digits). Also, I don't know what the `S` and the `'` are doing there:

```
/^[0-9.-]+$/
```

Also, I can promise you that after taking the time to read through [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) regular expressions will seem a lot less confusing to you.

Comment: hmm, people here down voting my question i dont care but I am getting useful knowledge by genious peoples, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You simply haven't used the literal dash `-` (or minus) in the regex. Try:

```
/^[0-9\.-]+$/
```

But if you want a proper number, you might want to use a more proper regex:

```
/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

The first regex can accept things such as `3987----....` while the second will not accept it, but will accept things like `-87.983274`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex.

```
/^-?[0-9\.]+$/
```